# Javascript clear cache image

Tags: php, javascript, image, caching, upload

I have a PHP script that I use to display images that are below the root directory. In Javascript, when I use the script to display an image, the image is displayed normally. However, when the image is modified without the page is reloaded, the old image is displayed instead of the new image. I've tried to add a timestamp to the image, but it seems that this only works when the image is displayed through the script.
Code from image display in PHP:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents( $_GET['arquivo'] );
if( $content !== false ){
    echo $content;
}
else{
    echo 'not found';   
}
?>
```

Sample image using this script:

```
<img src = "http://www.mysite.com/general/showimage.php?arquivo=/directory/temp1.jpeg">
```

I have tried this:

```
<img src = "http://www.mysite.com/general/showimage.php?arquivo=/directory/temp1.jpeg?k=123041">
```

But, in this way, no image is displayed, not even the old.

I use it on a upload system that doesn't reload the page.

Comment: use `&` to separate multiple parameters, not `?`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<img src = "http://www.mysite.com/general/showimage.php?arquivo=/directory/temp1.jpeg&k=123041">
```

Your first parameter begin after `?`, and any subsequent should be added using `&`

Comment: Thank you for the fast asnwer. This worked. I put the "?" before the parameter k because I thought it was a parameter inside of the parameter arquivo.
I thought I should do as you do when you want to reload an image in Javascript by browser:
<img src = "http://www.mysite.com/image.png?k=123041">

Comment: @MaxLuppertini it is easy to make such mistakes

Answer (score 0):

This is because the generated url is not valid, you have two `?`s in it:

```
http://www.mysite.com/general/showimage.php?arquivo=/directory/temp1.jpeg?k=123041
                                           ^                             ^
```

You will have to use '&' before the second parameter.